# What is wrong with print_binary function with negative number as argument?

Tags: c

I want to print an integer number in binary mode using following function:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void print_binary(int n)
{
    int i = 0;

    for (i = sizeof(n)*8 - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        printf("%d", ((n & ((1 << (i + 1)) - 1)) >> i) ? 1 : 0);
    }
}
```

main.c

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    printf("%d in binary:\n", atoi(argv[1]));
    print_binary(atoi(argv[1]));
    printf("\n");

    printf("%d in hex: 0x%x\n", atoi(argv[1]), atoi(argv[1]));

    return 0;
}
```

if I passed -1 into it, the output is incorrect, what is wrong?

```
-1 in binary:
01111111111111111111111111111111
-1 in hex: 0xffffffff
```

What causes the most significant bit to become 0?

Comment: The program you've pasted, verbatim, can result in a [segmentation fault](http://ideone.com/lR4wx)

Comment: You should run it with argument

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This expression `1 << (i + 1)`  is undefined behavior when `i + 1 == 32` (i.e., `>= CHAR_BIT * sizeof (int)` in your platform.

> (C99, 6.5.7p3) "If the value of the right operand is negative or is greater than or equal to the width of the promoted left operand, the behavior is undefined."

Comment: I got it, it is really a big issue

Answer (score 1):

The expression in your `printf` call can be simplified:

```
printf("%d", (n >> i) & 1);
```

Incidentally, this will also solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, shifting `1` by >=32(`sizeof(int)`) bits will result in undefined behavior.

Why all the complexity while printing out the bits? A simple

```
for (i = sizeof(n)*8 - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    printf("%d", n & (1 << i)  ? 1 : 0);
}
```

[will do](http://ideone.com/phIMX) what you want.

Comment: Not just `> sizeof(type)`, but actually `>= sizeof(type)`.

Comment: Also, for portability `CHAR_BIT` should be used instead of 8 and signed overflows (e.g. `1<<sizeof(int)-1`) should be avoided.